# Proving that $\angle B\le60^\circ$

Tags: geometry

> $A$ is the smallest angle of $\triangle ABC$. The height from $A$ over $BC$ is equal to the median from $B$. Prove that $\angle B\le 60^\circ$.

I tried extending the median to construct a parallelogram and expressed the area in terms of $BC$, the height over $BC$ and the median, but didn't succeed.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site, indicate what you have tried, and explain where you are stuck.

Comment: Can you explain us what the bisector of $AC$ from $B$ means? Is it the median?

Comment: Yes, I will edit the question sorry.

Comment: Can you tell me where did you find this question? I'm certain I've seen it as a contest problem somewhere.

Comment: Yes, it was asked at regional Olympiads.

Comment: @kk2111 Can you remind me which country? Maybe which year?

Comment: Albania 2012-2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the median partitions the triangle into two triangles with the same area. Hence if $M$ is the midpoint of $AC$ we have: $$[MBC] = \frac{[ABC]}{2} \implies \frac{BC \cdot BM \cdot \sin \angle MBC}{2} = \frac{BC \cdot h_a}{4} $$
$$\implies \sin \angle MBC = \frac 12 \implies \angle MBC = \frac{\pi}{6} $$

Similarly:

$$[MBA] = \frac{[ABC]}{2} \implies \frac{BA \cdot BM \cdot \sin \angle MBA}{2} = \frac{BA \cdot h_c}{4} $$
$$\implies \sin \angle MBC = \frac 12 \cdot \frac{h_b}{h_a} \le \frac 12 \implies \angle MBC \le \frac{\pi}{6} $$

Therefore $\angle B = \angle BMA + \angle BMC \le \frac{\pi}{3}$

Comment: Got it, I was so close :(